# Weird issue in bing maps display

Tags: bing-maps

I am displaying bing maps in a metro app. I am drawing both pushpins and polylines on the map but they get drawn on opposite sides of the map which looks very weird. Please look at the following image:[image]

The line and image is being drawn at opposite sides of the map.

Could someone please suggest a solution of this problem.

Can I somehow restrict my view to display each country only once?

Answer (score 2):

So I think one of my other answer might help you out here.

[How to show the full map and prevent scrolling in Bing Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051927/how-to-show-the-full-map-and-prevent-scrolling-in-bing-maps-api/11057809#11057809)

You can constrain the map to a certain zoomlevel range and lat/long range, so that you don't see the same coordinates twice. Let me know if you need any further details on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, but how it will work for this zoom level as shown in the image? I can not restrict the zoom level however I can afford to show the blank area (i.e. filled with background color), where duplicate tiles are being shown. Is this possible to do?

Comment: why do you have to show this zoomlevel? Im not sure what the map does if you tell it to constrain the view to the natural set of lat/longs, but you don't restrict the zoomlevel range. It might behave how you would like it to.

Comment: Bryan Watts is absolutely correct - if you're plotting data elements at latitude/longitude coordinates on the map, it's important that those coordinates only exist at one unique location. Why would you ever want to display a map that shows australia twice?! Restrict the zoom level and/or reduce the overall extent of the map control so that this does not occur and your problem will be solved :)